# Why do my clients hate anything below 12 pt?

Tags: typesetting

Why is it the majority of my clients absolutely refuse to go below 12 point for body copy? No matter how many stunning examples I provide, or how many people whose work I credit, they always scoff and say that the type's too small for them to read. I use a healthy balance of serif and sans-serif, and try to stick with taller x-heights and healthier widths, but it's just no use. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure how anyone here would know why your clients have a specific preference or how to speak to your clients specifically.

Comment: There is not one "right" answer but: 12 looks good on screen, so if they look at it only on a screen they will feel that this is a good choice. Secondly, 12 was default for MS Word if I am not mistaken and people got used to it. Thirdly: people who have to judge on font sizes for the first time (or any design decision) tend to go with what they feel is least risky. Ergo, bigger logo, bigger text, boring colors.

Comment: So many questions not answered here ... What types of projects are you showing your clients with less than 12 point fonts?  What goals to do your clients have? Who is your target audience? How old are they? How old are your clients?  Do they require reading glasses?  To put it simply ... Business needs and research should dictate design elements ... If you're designing something simply to be pretty, without properly aligning your design to meet business goals, then your doing it wrong.